# Unknown triax connector

Tags: connector

The **Input** connector on Agilent/Keysight 4339B is atypical.

A "normal" or most common triax has two or three lugs, on the outer rim of the male, and the female has corresponding nothces to fit and to lock onto with a twist movement (same way as BNC does). This type has screws on both male and female.

The 4339B was manufactured in the 80's (I think, and in Japan I think) for high resistance measurements so the 3rd guard was for eliminating leakage current through the cable insulation. The info is not included in the user, maintenance, or accessories manuals of the instrument. The manufacturer company has merged and people who made this are not accessible anymore.

Does anyone know what the **Input** connector make and model these are (both male and female)?

Male [image: Male]

Both [image: Male and Female]

Female side view [image: Female side view]

Female[image: Female]

Comment: atypical in what way?

Comment: Google for **T**NC triax. B→Bajonet T→Twist.

Comment: Looks like 3 conductors, and not a typical 2 conductor TNC, based on some image searches. T is also supposed to stand for threaded, not twisted. @janka

Comment: I've been told that the connector is "RF triax cable for high frequencies". I am working on verifying this.

Comment: https://groups.io/g/Test-Equipment-For-Sale-Wanted-or-Exchange/topic/has_anyone_got_any_of_these/16303641?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,20,16303641

Comment: https://www.skgautomation.com/agilent-4339b.html

Answer (score 1):

These people make them, they were very hard to find and in this type of context it is OK to post a link https://www.skgautomation.com/agilent-4339b.html